# How to force facebookexternalhit to reaccess?

Tags: facebook

I'm playing with facebook links via posting them. On the frist time a access from a user agent containing "facebookexternalhit" will visit your site and look for [some meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/).

So far so good that works. But if I try to repost the link no furure calls happens. How can I trigger to let facebook read the page again?

Are there some API calls I can use to trigger an update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the documentation for the [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) it says:

> **When does Facebook scrape my page?**
>
> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
>   the site.
>
> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are
>   up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph
>   page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the
>   Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it
>   will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference.
>   However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your
>   page every 24 hours.
>
> The user agent of the scraper is: "facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

The Linter is now known as the [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and when you use it for a url, it will clear the facebook cache for the same url and will then cache the new result.

Comment: But I don't use Like Buttons yet. I'm talking just about posting links. Is that threated the same way? Will the user posting been updated after 24 hours?

Comment: I just took that part from the Like Button doc., but that specific info is more general. They probably should find another place to put it, but for now it's there. The main point is that using the Debugger you can force a cache clean, just try it.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the Facebook Debugger, I was able to force a new scrape after mod_security was denying facebookexternalhit and I removed the rule.

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can use is to simply append a "random" GET parameter to the URL that you're sharing.  It won't have any effect on the page's content, but will cause Facebook's scraper bot to reaccess your site.

Original URLs:

```
http://example.com
http://example.com?param=1
```

New URLs that will force a "reaccess":

```
http://example.com?cache_buster=784932789532
http://example.com?param=1&cache_buster=784932789532
```